# Error in build while using keras custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to train an unsupervised classification model for which i am using deep clustering with my model on Keras. 
The code I am referring for clustering is [this](https://github.com/XifengGuo/DCEC/blob/master/DCEC.py).
While running the code i am getting an error in the cutom layer while adding weights. Below you can see the Code and the error.

````
import metrics
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, InputSpec
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

class ClusteringLayer(Layer):
    """
    Clustering layer converts input sample (feature) to soft label, i.e. a vector that represents the probability of the
    sample belonging to each cluster. The probability is calculated with student's t-distribution.
    # Example
    ```
        model.add(ClusteringLayer(n_clusters=10))
    ```
    # Arguments
        n_clusters: number of clusters.
        weights: list of Numpy array with shape `(n_clusters, n_features)` witch represents the initial cluster centers.
        alpha: parameter in Student's t-distribution. Default to 1.0.
    # Input shape
        2D tensor with shape: `(n_samples, n_features)`.
    # Output shape
        2D tensor with shape: `(n_samples, n_clusters)`.
    """

    def __init__(self, n_clusters, weights=None, alpha=1.0, **kwargs):
        if 'input_shape' not in kwargs and 'input_dim' in kwargs:
            kwargs['input_shape'] = (kwargs.pop('input_dim'),)
        super(ClusteringLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.n_clusters = n_clusters
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.initial_weights = weights
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(ndim=2)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 2
        input_dim = input_shape[1]
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(dtype=K.floatx(), shape=(None, input_dim))
        self.clusters = self.add_weight(shape=(self.n_clusters, input_dim), initializer='glorot_uniform', name='clusters')
        if self.initial_weights is not None:
            self.set_weights(self.initial_weights)
            del self.initial_weights
        self.built = True

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        """ student t-distribution, as same as used in t-SNE algorithm.
                 q_ij = 1/(1+dist(x_i, u_j)^2), then normalize it.
        Arguments:
            inputs: the variable containing data, shape=(n_samples, n_features)
        Return:
            q: student's t-distribution, or soft labels for each sample. shape=(n_samples, n_clusters)
        """
        q = 1.0 / (1.0 + (K.sum(K.square(K.expand_dims(inputs, axis=1) - self.clusters), axis=2) / self.alpha))
        q **= (self.alpha + 1.0) / 2.0
        q = K.transpose(K.transpose(q) / K.sum(q, axis=1))
        return q

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        assert input_shape and len(input_shape) == 2
        return input_shape[0], self.n_clusters

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'n_clusters': self.n_clusters}
        base_config = super(ClusteringLayer, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

class Inf:
    def __init__(self, D1, D2, n_clusters):
        from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json

        self.n_clusters = n_clusters
        json_file = open(D1, 'r')
        loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
        json_file.close()
        loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
        # load weights into new model
        loaded_model.load_weights(D2)
        print("Loaded model from disk")
        loaded_model.summary()
        self.model = loaded_model

    def create_model(self):
        hidden = self.model.get_layer(name='encoded').output
        self.encoder = Model(inputs = self.model.input, outputs = hidden)       
        clustering_layer = ClusteringLayer(n_clusters=self.n_clusters)(hidden)
        self.model = Model(inputs = self.model.input, outputs = clustering_layer)
        self.model = model

    def compile(self, loss='kld', optimizer='adam'):
        self.model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)

    def fit(self, x, y=None, batch_size=16, maxiter=2e4, tol=1e-3, update_interval=140, save_dir='./results/temp'):
        print('Update interval', update_interval)
        save_interval = x.shape[0] / batch_size * 5
        print('Save interval', save_interval)

        print('Initializing cluster centers with k-means.')
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=self.n_clusters, n_init=20)
        self.y_pred = kmeans.fit_predict(self.encoder.predict(x))
        y_pred_last = np.copy(self.y_pred)
        self.model.get_layer(name='clustering').set_weights([kmeans.cluster_centers_])

        # Step : deep clustering
        # logging file
        import csv, os
        if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
            os.makedirs(save_dir)
        logfile = open(save_dir + '/dcec_log.csv', 'w')
        logwriter = csv.DictWriter(logfile, fieldnames=['iter', 'acc', 'nmi', 'ari', 'L', 'Lc', 'Lr'])
        logwriter.writeheader()

        loss = [0, 0, 0]
        index = 0
        for ite in range(int(maxiter)):
            if ite % update_interval == 0:
                q, _ = self.model.predict(x, verbose=0)
                p = self.target_distribution(q)  # update the auxiliary target distribution p

                # evaluate the clustering performance
                self.y_pred = q.argmax(1)
                if y is not None:
                    acc = np.round(metrics.acc(y, self.y_pred), 5)
                    nmi = np.round(metrics.nmi(y, self.y_pred), 5)
                    ari = np.round(metrics.ari(y, self.y_pred), 5)
                    loss = np.round(loss, 5)
                    logdict = dict(iter=ite, acc=acc, nmi=nmi, ari=ari, L=loss[0], Lc=loss[1], Lr=loss[2])
                    logwriter.writerow(logdict)
                    print('Iter', ite, ': Acc', acc, ', nmi', nmi, ', ari', ari, '; loss=', loss)

                # check stop criterion
                delta_label = np.sum(self.y_pred != y_pred_last).astype(np.float32) / self.y_pred.shape[0]
                y_pred_last = np.copy(self.y_pred)
                if ite > 0 and delta_label < tol:
                    print('delta_label ', delta_label, '< tol ', tol)
                    print('Reached tolerance threshold. Stopping training.')
                    logfile.close()
                    break

            # train on batch
            if (index + 1) * batch_size > x.shape[0]:
                loss = self.model.train_on_batch(x=x[index * batch_size::],
                                                 y=[p[index * batch_size::], x[index * batch_size::]])
                index = 0
            else:
                loss = self.model.train_on_batch(x=x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size],
                                                 y=[p[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size],
                                                    x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]])
                index += 1

            # save intermediate model
            if ite % save_interval == 0:
                # save DCEC model checkpoints
                print('saving model to:', save_dir + '/dcec_model_' + str(ite) + '.h5')
                self.model.save_weights(save_dir + '/dcec_model_' + str(ite) + '.h5')

            ite += 1

        # save the trained model
        logfile.close()
        print('saving model to:', save_dir + '/dcec_model_final.h5')
        self.model.save_weights(save_dir + '/dcec_model_final.h5')
````

My Output layer is a dense layer with output dimension(?,128).
I am getting a following error in the clustering layer.

```
  File "C:/Users/u/Desktop/trained/inference.py", line 45, in build
    self.clusters = self.add_weight(shape=(self.n_clusters, input_dim), initializer='glorot_uniform', name='clusters')

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 384, in add_weight
    aggregation=aggregation)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 663, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
    **kwargs_for_getter)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_utils.py", line 155, in make_variable
    shape=variable_shape if variable_shape.rank else None)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 259, in __call__
    return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 220, in _variable_v1_call
    shape=shape)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 198, in <lambda>
    previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py", line 2495, in default_variable_creator
    shape=shape)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py", line 263, in __call__
    return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 460, in __init__
    shape=shape)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 604, in _init_from_args
    initial_value() if init_from_fn else initial_value,

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_utils.py", line 135, in <lambda>
    init_val = lambda: initializer(shape, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\init_ops.py", line 533, in __call__
    shape, -limit, limit, dtype, seed=self.seed)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\random_ops.py", line 239, in random_uniform
    shape = _ShapeTensor(shape)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\random_ops.py", line 44, in _ShapeTensor
    return ops.convert_to_tensor(shape, dtype=dtype, name="shape")

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1087, in convert_to_tensor
    return convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, preferred_dtype, name)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1145, in convert_to_tensor_v2
    as_ref=False)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1224, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 305, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 246, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 284, in _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))

  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_util.py", line 562, in make_tensor_proto
    "supported type." % (type(values), values))

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor. Contents: (17, Dimension(128)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

I have used an autoencoder's encoder past as an input. Following is the encoder part of the autoencoder.

```
ip = Input(shape=(256,256,1))


x = Conv2D(16, (3,3), padding='same')(ip)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), padding='same')(x)

x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(128, name="encoded")(x)
```

Comment: It would help if you can provide the complete code. Also, what's your input?

Comment: I have added the encoder's output as input. I guess this much knowledge is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
input_dim = input_shape[1].value
```

With

```
input_dim = input_shape[1]
```

and also Replace

```
if (index + 1) * batch_size > x.shape[0]:
    loss = self.model.train_on_batch(x=x[index * batch_size::], y=[p[index * batch_size::], x[index * batch_size::]])
    index = 0
else:
    loss = self.model.train_on_batch(x=x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size], y=[p[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size], x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]])
    index += 1
```

With

```
if (index + 1) * batch_size > x.shape[0]:
    loss = self.model.train_on_batch(x=x[index * batch_size::], y=p[index * batch_size::])
    index = 0
else:
    loss = self.model.train_on_batch(x=x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size], y=p[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size])
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
input_dim = input_shape[1]
```

with

```
input_dim = input_shape[1].value
```

in the `build()` method of `ClusteringLayer`, so that input_dim will be 128 instead of Dimension(128).